# NSCollectionView indexPathForItem(at: point) returns nil for first item

Tags: macos, cocoa, nscollectionview

I'm using a NSCollectionView with a standard NSCollectionViewFlowLayout in a MacOS app (SDK 10.13).

For whatever reason the item at `IndexPath(item: 0, section: 0)` is not properly 'recognized'.

For example querying `indexPathForItem(at: point)` for this item returns nil. Also delegate methods like `collectionView(_ collectionView: NSCollectionView, didSelectItemsAt indexPaths: Set<IndexPath>)` are not called for this specific item.

All other items in the collectionView behave correctly.

When triggering `collectionView.layout()` explicitly (e.g. in `rightMouseDown(_:)`), everything works fine and the item responds to the delegate methods.

I tried to trigger `collectionView.layout()` in `viewDidLoad()` without success. The item is not selectable until a subsequent layout event (e.g. scrolling the view) happens.

Any ideas why the initial layout results in such a behaviour?

---

**Update:**

I just discovered that commenting out the delegate method for the section header size

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: NSCollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: NSCollectionViewLayout, referenceSizeForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> NSSize {
    return NSSize(width: 1000, height: 50)
}
```

resolves the issue and the first item behaves correctly.

Of course I do want a header. Are there any constraints for the section header size I'd need to be aware of?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, nevermind. Turns out to be my fault.

For the scenario where the issue occurred I wanted to suppress the header.

Lazy as I am I just returned a plain NSView() as the header view in

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: NSCollectionView, viewForSupplementaryElementOfKind kind: NSCollectionView.SupplementaryElementKind, at indexPath: IndexPath) -> NSView
```

I guess not returning a properly layout-constrained view messed up the collectionView layout.